# Django - Storing results of query

Tags: django

I have a 'categories' model which I is used more than once on a page. Since I am obtaining all the categories at the start, I want to cut down on database queries by obtaining the same data more than once.

Since the initial query is getting ALL the categories, is there a way to store this information in the model so that when I reference the data again later, I don't have to hit the database again?

Perhaps some kind of associative array or dict which stores the categories?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Django querysets are [lazy](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) and [cached](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets), so the database is not hit till the queryset is accessed. You should also take a look at [how queries are evaluated](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

If you could post some code, we could help you figure out an optimal way to write queries.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really have any code, it's more of a general question. If you imagine a blog, you may want to have the categories listed on the right hand side.. but you'd also show individual categories for each entry in blog on the left. Since we already hit the database obtaining the list of categories for the right hand side of the page, I wouldn't want to do so again for the individual blog entries.

Comment: @Hanpan - but those are two completely different queries, you're going to have to ask them both, so I'm not sure how a cache would help.

Comment: Hitting the DB twice isn't a problem. Hitting it for every blog in a big listing might be. You'll probably have to work hard (by 'hard' I mean 'stupidly') to make Django do that.